Podman: remap users of mapped volumes
I am running Nginx and PHP in a rootless podman container. Using a Quadlet, I am mounting three host volumes into the container:
# ~/.config/containers/systemd/mywebsite.container
[Unit]
Description=website

[Container]
Image=localhost/mywebsite:latest
ContainerName=mywebsite
PublishPort=127.0.0.1:8081:80
Volume=/home/myuser/mywebsite/html:/var/www/html
Volume=/home/myuser/mywebsite/logs:/var/www/logs
Volume=/home/myuser/mywebsite/database:/var/www/database

[Service]
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=900

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

Inside the container Nginx runs as user nginx:nginx, and PHP as nobody:nobody. However, when I start the container they both seem to write log files as user root:
$ podman exec mywebsite ls -l /var/www/logs
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 17:09 access.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 17:09 error.log
-rw-------    1 root     root           112 Oct 21 17:09 php-fpm.log

Which is nice because that makes it easy from the host-side because they map on my user:
$ ls -l mywebsite/logs
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   0 Oct 21 17:09 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   0 Oct 21 17:09 error.log
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 112 Oct 21 17:09 php-fpm.log

The static website content files (.html, .jpg, .php, etc.) are owned by myuser on the host, and therefore nicely mounted as root inside the container, making them read-only for the Nginx and PHP:
$ ls -l mywebsite/html/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1692 Oct 21 14:16 conelayout/html/index.php

$ podman exec mywebsite ls -l /var/www/html/index.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1692 Oct 21 14:16 /var/www/html/index.php

However, to allow SQLite3 to write database files from PHP, those files must have nobody:nobody ownership:
$ podman exec mywebsite ls -l /var/www/database
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody       12288 Oct 21 16:41 mydatabase.sqlite

which results in an inconvenient 165533 ownership on the host:
$ ls -l mywebsite/database
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 165533 165533 12288 Oct 21 16:41 mydatabase.sqlite

Is there a way to remap user ids per volume so that I can keep the convenient mapping for html/ and logs/ and remap only database/ to my regular user on the host?
